# I modified the following C++ program, but did i get it correct?

Tags: c++

In the analysis of the following program my book says, "In this sample, the input parameter containing the number sent by the user has been modified. If you need both values, the original and the square, you can have the function accept two parameters: one that contains the input and the other that supplies the square."

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void ReturnSquare(int& Number)
 {
     Number *= Number;
 }


 int main()
 {
     cout<< "enter a number you wish to square: ";
     int Number = 0;
     cin>> Number;

     ReturnSquare(Number);
     cout<< "square is: " << Number <<endl;

     cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
     cin.ignore(10, '\n');
     cin.get();
     return 0;
 }
```

I made a quite extensive modification to this program, which compiles and runs properly, but did I demonstrate what the book was asking me to correctly? Please help me I am only beginning. Modification follows:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void ReturnSquare(int& Number, int Number2)
 {
     cout<< "do you wish to add number ?...(y/n) ";
     char CalcCircum = 'n';
     cin>> CalcCircum;

     if (CalcCircum == 'n' || 'y')
     Number *= Number;

     if (CalcCircum =='y')
     cout<< "addition of number is..." << Number2 + Number2 <<endl;
 }  


 int main()
 {
     cout<< "enter a number you wish to square: ";
     int Number = 0;
     cin>> Number;

     ReturnSquare(Number, Number);
     cout<< "square is: " << Number <<endl;

     cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
     cin.ignore(10, '\n');
     cin.get();
     return 0;
 }
```

Please tell me Where my admittedly little experienced thinking has, as I suspect, gone wrong. Thank you all, sincerely newmanadam

Comment: It does not appear that you did it right. although what is asking for is pointless.  The function should return the square but alas that is not what they want.

Comment: `if (CalcCircum == 'n' || 'y')` is not correct. Because it means the same as `if (true)`

Comment: Perhaps, but it compiles, runs, and does what output says it will. Try it out. Thank you

Comment: Comment out the if part and there will be no difference in execution. `Number *= Number;` is executed always.

Comment: Obviously you are more experienced than me as I hadn't noticed that. thank you. Peace my fellow, and much more experienced C++ coder

Answer (score 0):

The exercise asks for a very unconventional manner to return a value.

```
void calc(int argument, int& returnValue){
    returnValue = argument * argument; }
```

You have to call it in an odd way:

```
int returnValue;
int square = 17;
calc(square, returnValue);

std::cout << returnValue;
```

You might see 289 on your console.

Comment: Note that, obviously I am aware that parameter3 is always squared in the resulting program I made. I was merely trying to demonstrate what the book was asking me to do. Please explain what I didn't do, or what I could have done differently. Thank you all          PS. the book was avoiding using a return statement here.

Answer (score 0):

You made it a lot more complicated that it needs to be. Change the function to:

```
void ReturnSquare(int in, int& out)
{
   out = in*in;
}
```

and then change `main` to:

```
int main()
{
   cout<< "enter a number you wish to square: ";
   int messaround = 0;
   cin>> messaround;

   int sq;
   ReturnSquare(messaround, sq);

   cout<< "original number is: " << messaround <<endl;
   cout<< "square is: " << sq <<endl;

   cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
   cin.ignore(10, '\n');
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how OP's code is "a lot more complicated" than your code. It looks identical except for the method of passing a value (of which yours is more verbose)

Comment: @M.M, the second version of `ReturnSquare` is needlessly complicated.

Comment: the second version in the OP is adding new functionality

Comment: @M.M, I agree that it has new functionality but I thought it was not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

This very slight variation of my modified problem program also works, and is perhaps slightly more readable. Variation follows:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void ReturnSquare(int& Number, int Number2)
 {
     cout<< "do you wish to add number ?...(y/n) ";
     char CalcCircum = 'n';
     cin>> CalcCircum;


     Number *= Number;

     if (CalcCircum =='y')
     cout<< "addition of number is..." << Number2 + Number2 <<endl;
 }


 int main()
 {
     cout<< "enter a number you wish to square: ";
     int messaround = 0;
     cin>> messaround;

     ReturnSquare(messaround, messaround);
     cout<< "square is: " << messaround <<endl;

     cout<< "press enter to continue..." <<endl;
     cin.ignore(10, '\n');
     cin.get();
     return 0;
 }
```

Thank you all very much. Much respect from a newbie programmer (but hopefully not by this time next year). Peace to all fellow coders, sincerely, newmanadam

Comment: You should check whether `cin>> CalcCircum;` succeeded. It looks like you're assuming that if input fails then `CalcCircum` retains its previous value but this is not true (in fact the C++ standard specifies it to be set to `0` in that case, although it may not be wise to rely on that fact).

Comment: It's a bad idea to have the one function `ReturnSquare` perform two completely separate tasks (the squaring and the input-and-addition), you should have two separate functions.